# Annoying behaviour in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

In a web page I have 2 different galleries with several images. Each image has a button assigned in order to be deleted. I decided to use the same JavaScript function with a parameter to differentiate both galleries. These are the galleries:

```
        <div class="column col_12 gallery">
            {% for testrigimage in testrigimages %}
                <div id="testRigImage_{{testrigimage.id}}" class="image" align="center">
                    <a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{testrigimage.image}}"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{testrigimage.image}}" width="150" height="100" /></a>
                    <i id="deleteTestRigImage_{{testrigimage.id}}" class="icon-remove-sign icon-large" style="display:none;cursor:pointer;color:darkGrey;position:absolute;top:9px;left:129px;" onclick="javascript:deleteFile('{{testrigimage.id}}','0');"></i>
                    <br>
                    {{testrigimage.name}}
                </div>
            {% empty %}
                No images have been added.
            {% endfor %}
        </div>


    <div class="column col_12 gallery">
        {% for picture in pictures %}
            <div id="picture_{{picture.id}}" class="image" align="center">
                <a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{picture.image}}"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{picture.image}}" width="150" height="100" /></a>
                <i id="deletePicture_{{picture.id}}" class="icon-remove-sign icon-large" style="display:none;cursor:pointer;color:darkGrey;position:absolute;top:9px;left:129px;" onclick="javascript:deleteFile('{{picture.id}}','1');"></i>
                <br>
                {{picture.name}}
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            No pictures have been added.
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

As you could observe, both galleries are similar. The only difference is in the "onclick" attribute of the  element. To differentiate both I pass to the function "deleteFile" an extra parameter: "0" or "1". This is the "deleteFile" function:

```
function deleteFile(model_id, type){

    var x = confirm('You are about to delete this picture. Are you sure?')

    if(type="0"){
        alert(type)
        url = "/tests/testSetUp/testrig/" + model_id + "/delete/"
    }else{
        alert(type)
        url = "/tests/testSetUp/pictures/" + model_id + "/delete/"
    }

    if (x) {

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url : url,
             data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
             dataType: 'text',
             success : function (data, textStatus, request) {
             data = eval("(" + data + ")");
             if (data.success) {
                var n = noty({
                    text: 'Picture successfully removed.',
                    type: 'success',
                    timeout: 750,
                    callback:{
                        afterClose: function(){location.reload()}
                    }
                });             
            }
             else {
                var n = noty({
                    text: 'Error. Please, contact with the administrator.',
                    type: 'error',
                    timeout: 3000
                });
             } 
             }
        });


    }

}
```

And the problems is that always print (alert) "0"! When I click in a image of the first gallery (the one with the "0" parameter), it alerts 0. When I click in a image of the second gallery, it alerts "0" too, despite having assigned "1".

Why this behaviour??

Comment: `if(type="0")` should be `if(type=="0")` or even `if(type==="0")`. a single "equals" sign is for assignment, and an assignment always returns true

Comment: A tool such as `jshint` would have found this for you.

Comment: I still make this typo from time to time.  As torazaburo mentioned, look into jshint.  http://jshint.com/ will let you copy/paste or many code editors contain the functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this line in your code  `if (type="0")`.

To check for equality it needs to be `if (type=="0")` or `if (type === "0")`.

Using a `=` will assign the value and evaluate to the value being assigned, while `==` or `===` will compare the two values.

Comment: _"Value assignment always returns true"_ This is not remotely correct. Value assignment returns the value being assigned.

Comment: In the case of `if(something=0`) then that statement will pass or return true, it will not fail.  Feel free to suggest an edit as that is how that that statement showed up in the first place.

Comment: Observe: http://jsfiddle.net/3ob9ekno/ I'll edit your post if that's what you want. The first edit should have been rejected as invalid.